# Can browser invoke Oracle stored procedures directly?

Tags: javascript, oracle, web-services, stored-procedures, browser

My application's front end is developed using Angular 5 framework and database using Oracle. Oracle has exposed some Stored Procedures (SPs). Generally we convert these SPs into Web Services/APIs using some middle ware such as .Net or Java which browser can consume.

I would like to know- if browser can directly consume those SPs without being converted into  web services?

Comment: There are possibilities, but you usually don’t want the login-credentials for your database to be provided in the front end in cause of security issues.

Comment: If there are possibilities, I would like to know HOW? let's keep the security issues apart.

Comment: We can expose RESTful interfaces for stored procedures directly  in the database - that is, with no additional tiers - using Oracle REST Data Services. [Find out more](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/rest.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no. The database doesn't generally listen on port 80. Probably the easiest thing you can do is set up a web service with ORDS and point your browser at that.

Here is the link to Oracle Rest Data Services: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/rest.html

Comment: Afaik you can use every Port, by using http to connect to anything like webapi/theoretically also to a database, if it’s reachable.

Comment: Only if the recipient is listening on that port. I don't know of any way to get into the database without some other component, at least ORDS.

Comment: But just not knowing doesn’t mean, there isn’t a way. Btw it’s asked for a way without a webservice and APC provides a way in his comment.

Comment: ORDS is a "mid-tier Java application" and requires a web server.